# Compare a list of tuple with a list of string - Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I try compare a result of a query with a list, but give me an error. 
like:

```
Index 0: ('abc', 1, 'cde') (tuple) != ('abc', 1, 'cde') (string)
```

I have no experience in python.

what can I  do?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add more details to the question like what the robotframework command you are running is and the error you are seeing?

Comment: I try with this keyword  'Lists Should Be Equal  ${list1tuple}  ${list1string} '

Answer (score 1):

This seems a data compatibility issue. You are comparing a tuple data with a String data. You need to convert tuple data to string or vice versa.